# how to translate the string with nonprintable character in java

Tags: java, string

I want to translate the string with non-printable character(backslash, left arrow, right arrow, etc) into printable string in java programming.

> For example -
>
> input string = "rn -r\b\b\b\b -r[K\b\b\bm -r\b\b\b"
>
> byte array of input string =
>      [114, 110, 32, 45, 114, 8, 8, 8, 8, 32, 45, 114, 27, 91, 75, 8, 8, 8, 109, 32, 45, 114, 8, 8, 8]
>
> output string should be = "rm -r"

How can I translate this string into printable string?

Comment: Sure you can, you just need to replicate the shell behavior. I'm not sure there's a lib for that.

Comment: do you want to remove non-printable characters?

Comment: How is output string `rm -r` and not `rm -r [K  -r`?

Comment: What do you want to do with these lines?  byte array of input string = [114, 110, 32, 45, 114, 8, 8, 8, 8, 32, 45, 114, 27, 91, 75, 8, 8, 8, 109, 32, 45, 114, 8, 8, 8]

Comment: The output string should be "rm-r".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean removing non-printable characters

```
System.out.println("rn -r\b\b\b\b -r[K\b\b\bm -r\b\b\b".replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""));
```

output

```
rn -r -r[Km -r
```

**UPDATE**

this version maintains a cursor and supports backspace, left arrow and right arrow

```
    String s = "rn -r\b\b\b\b -r[K\b\b\bm -r\b\b\b";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cursor = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '\b') {
            if (cursor > 0) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(--cursor);
            }
        } else if (c == 37) {   // left arrow
            if (cursor > 0) {
                cursor--;
            }
        } else if (c == 39) {   // right arrow
            if (cursor < sb.length()) {
                cursor++;
            }
        } else if (!Character.isISOControl(c)) {
            sb.insert(cursor++, c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

prints `r -m`.

It's different from your `rm -r` but I think mine is correct

Comment: regex was supposed to be "\\P{Print}", got distorted during copypaste

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by to translate?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I not only want to remove non-printable character but also want to operate the task of this character. For example, When backslash character(\b) contains in a string "test\b", we will need to remove the backslash character and we will also need to delete the before character of this, so, this string will be "tes".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer is meet with my question. I would like to know the library file or something like this for translating the string with non_printable character(such as- delete, backspace, left arrow, right arrow, up arrow, down arrow character) to console output string. But my question is not sufficient. I will ask with next question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the non printable characters you can do as below.

```
String input = "rn -r\b\b\b\b -r[K\b\b\bm -r\b\b\b";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string with non printable characters, iterate through the byte array representation of the String and convert each character(1 byte) into its Hex equivalent.

Remember, Integer representation of each Byte ranges from 0-255 which means Hex equivalent can range from 00 to FF. Therefore, each byte corresponds to two Hex characters.

Above logic gives a string a Hex String which will always contain printable characters (0,1,2..A,B..,F).